# Why Dropdown list data is erasing when I using the "SelectedIndexChanged" Event and initially data is filled by Ajax Method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have filled the data using Ajax Method `[WebMethod]` and Data is filling and next I have maintaining all logic from my server side code using `SelectedIndexChanged` event `AutoPostBack="true"` and I have used this dropdown control inside the `UpdatePanel` control in master page `MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" CodeBehind="AutoTrade.aspx.cs"'`.

ASP code :-

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="AutoTradeTop_expdate" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AutoTradeTop_expdate_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Ajax code :-

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //url is the path of our web method (Page name/function name)
            url: "AutoTrade.aspx/PopulateExpDate",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            //called on jquery ajax call success
            success: function (result) {
                $('#AutoTradeTop_expdate').empty();
                //$('#AutoTradeTop_expdate').append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");
                $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {
                    $("#AutoTradeTop_expdate").append($("<option></option>").val(value.ID).html(value.ExpDate));
                });

            },
            //called on jquery ajax call failure
            error: function ajaxError(result) {
                alert(result.status + ' : ' + result.statusText);
            }
        });
```

.cs code :-

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<AutoTradeExpDateRes> PopulateExpDate()
        {
            List<AutoTradeExpDateRes> autoTradeExpDateRes = new List<AutoTradeExpDateRes>();

            try
            {
                

                string expdateres = GetAPIResponse("ssss://xxx.com/fns.aspx?otype=analyse_expdate&uid=" + "62" + "&symbol=" + "nifty" + "&instrument=" + "ce" + "");
                var expdatelst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AutoTradeExpDateRes>>(expdateres);

                
                if (!ReferenceEquals(expdatelst, null) && expdatelst.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < expdatelst.Count; i++)
                    {
                        autoTradeExpDateRes.Add(new AutoTradeExpDateRes
                        {
                            ID= i,
                            ExpDate = Convert.ToString(expdatelst[i].ExpDate)
                        });;
                    }

                }

                return autoTradeExpDateRes;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

When I run this above code I'm getting the output Example Image :-

[image: dates data is coming]

But when I use codebehind `SelectedIndexChanged` event and select any one of the list vale from the dropdown list (the data is erasing)

```
protected void AutoTradeTop_expdate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

The dropdown list data is erasing example img

[image: Data erasing]

Note :- I know we can handle this data functionality by using this client side `onchange` event but my question can I handle this ajax filled data from server side ? (once event `SelectedIndexChanged` is triggering the data is erasing )

So I want to keep the data using this `SelectedIndexChanged` event without data erasing and my next functionality should work. Please suggest me how can I achieve this. And what are the possible ways.

(The main reason I'm asking this question is initially my dropdown data should load (I wrote ajax call for that) and next if I change any dropdown value my next functionality should work (dependency is there to another dropdown list) so if I write the `onchange` event for clientside I need to write the 'Ajax' call for that and should fetch data form 'WebMethod' codebehind (should write one for loop) and next that return list data should fetch and write another for loop in ajax call to avoid this repeat logic can we handle  from codebehind like my above question.)

Comment: Try to populate the dropdown data inside `!isPostBack`

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb thanks for your comment but when I call that method I will get object reference exception because Initially I'm loading the dropdown values using `WebMethod` so if call in `!isPostBack` I will end of with error. Suggest me with your best solution.

Comment: The $100, if not $200 dollar question? Why do you need to fil the ddl with ajax? You not demostrated the reason for this. If you fill or change the dll client side code, then the list of values does not persist. Now, that would susggest on each page load (actually page inti), then you have to re-load the ddl EACH time. But, until such time we determine why the dll must be filled by a ajax call, then a simple solution exists - simple file the ddl on page load - but only first page load (!IsPostBack), and all should be well.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thanks for your comment , I understand the concept of, from client side data filling and codebehind data filling (how it act).I have changed my code and now it is working fine.

Comment: I really wish that asp.net pages had an event called first load or even a open event. 2-5 posts per week on SO are the result of this simple issue. But we don't have a seperate event, and hence quite much every page that does setup and loading of data into controls thus will require a if !IsPostBack code stub for the "real" first page load where most of your page setup code will be placed. All good - and good luck

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal You giving good knowledge on doubts it is very happy to me for next moves and I have one more doubt on this concept if you clarify that it will give more confident to me that is I wrote the `autocomplete` textbox logic using ajax call and I'm filling the ddl from server side using `UpdatePanel` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event the code is executing fine but the `autocomplete` textbox logic is not working why ? so should I write all logic from clientside only ? or am I missing any key point plz guide me (if possible I will post this as an new question).

Comment: setup of autocomplete and that of the choices for a + DDL are two VAST HUGE different issues. If you want auto complete for a text box or a DDL, then fine. but loading up choices in a ddl is VERY different issue. The simple answer is you can't setup viewstate client side for the dll. But that is why I asked why the ddl list is not be filled server side. You can (and should fill the dll server side then). If you want to add auto-complete, then you are free to do so, but that is 100% separate from filling the dll.

Comment: If  you want to understand how viewstate works, then read this article: https://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate

Answer (score 0):

I have raised one query in comment session that is :

**I'm filling the ddl from server side using `UpdatePanel` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, the code is executing fine but the `autocomplete textbox` logic is not working why?**

I [found the solution for that query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867837/updatepanel-when-i-select-company-name-from-dropdown-list-autopostback-true-and) and it is working fine for me.

This is the main part of `autopostback` not working properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//On Page Load.
    SetAutoCompleteGuest();

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        SetAutoCompleteGuest();   // in this method write your code.        
    }
</script>
```